# CSS3 Question: how to have no box shadow on the top of a div?

Tags: css

Right now when I do this:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 200px #00C0FF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 200px #00C0FF;
box-shadow: 0 0 200px #00C0FF;
```

it gives a box shadow on all sides. I want it on 3 sides but not the top. How to prevent the shadow from appearing at the top?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can nest two divs then you should be able to use a combination of margins and `overflow:hidden` to 'chop off' the top shadow without losing the required effect on the other edges.

For example:

```css
.outer {
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 200px 200px 200px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 200px #00C0FF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 200px #00C0FF;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 200px #00C0FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is much less useful than Syafiq Zianal's answer as it requires more markup, more css and won't work at all if you don't have complete control of the markup.

Comment: You can use this same principle (cutting off the shadow) with z-index as well. I used z-index for my tab setup. Just make sure you include the position prop or z-index has no effect.

Comment: This is much MORE useful if you want to exactly use your existing box-shadow but clip part of it. (Syafiq's answer moves the shadow to remove the 'top' shadow, which only works if you're fine with the slightly larger shadow on one side)

Answer (score 48):

box-shadow support multiple commas which mean this is possible and can be done like below:

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888, -2px 2px 3px #888;
```

The first group bring shadow to the right & bottom while the second group bring shadow to the left (by using negative value) & bottom.

The complete code for cross browser support is:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888, -2px 2px 3px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888, -2px 2px 3px #888;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888, -2px 2px 3px #888;
```

Comment: This gives a shadow that is too long on the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Just have a [vertical offset only](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/):

```
.shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 200px #00C0FF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 200px #00C0FF;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 200px #00C0FF;
}
```

This will shift the shadow down so that the top has less of a shadow. You will have to play with it to get it the way you want it in your situation. [This site](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) also has some great info on box shadows, such as layering, as well as browser support.

Comment: cdeszaq is correct. you need to shift the center a bit down bu changing the 0 0 part.

Comment: This is actually *not* correct as it will cause the *bottom* shadow to then be 5px too big. I think what the OP is going for is exactly the shadow dimensions s/he already has applied, just without the top.

Comment: @robmclarty - Right, my solution doesn't provide the exact solution for the OP's situation, but the idea id shifting the shadow is the important part.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo-element to cover the edge of the element you don't want to have a shadow. This is similar to ajcw's approach, but doesn't require manually adding the extra element every time — just once, in your CSS — and uses absolute positioning, which I think is much cleaner.

```css
.nav-link.active {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}

.nav-link.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 7px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: white;
  
  /*this one's only needed because we don't want this pseudo-element to be clickable*/
  pointer-events: none; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="p-4">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```