# Set CSS3 box-shadow not to be on top of div

Tags: css

I have a div box with box-shadow set around it with the following CSS:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #415a68;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #415a68;
-khtml-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #415a68;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #415a68;
```

What can I do to make box-shadow only apply to the left, right and bottom of the div?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 Question: how to have no box shadow on the top of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665341/css3-question-how-to-have-no-box-shadow-on-the-top-of-a-div)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>You cannot do this with **ONE** `div`</strike>.

**EDIT**

`box-shadow` does not allow right and left shadows at the same time.

*There is a trick, though...read on.*

The rule takes four values:

1. defines the horizontal offset of the shadow. + value for a right shadow and - value for a left shadow.
2. defines the vertical offset. + value for a bottom shadow and - value for a top shadow.
3. defines the blur distance
4. defines the spread

That is all true.  However, after some tests I found you can **layer** shadows.

All you need to do is separate the values with a comma.

So, for a left, right, and bottom shadow on one div, you can do this

```
box-shadow: -5px 5px 3px black, 5px 5px 3px black;
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/HWCzJ/1/

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the top shadow. Is it possible to remove a bottom shadow using this method?

Answer (score 3):

```css
div div
{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #415a68;   
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
div
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5rbrB/ here's an example using `overflow: hidden;` and `padding-top: 0;`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!