# 1px DropShadow Is Thicker on Bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a rounded rectangle and I am trying to apply a 1px blur, 1px vertical offet drop shadow to it. My problem is that the bottom drop-shadow looks significantly thicker then the one ones on the side. Is there a way to correct this so the bottom shadow will be the same width as the ones on the side? I thought of using `outline` but that would not work due to my rounded corners. Also, I do not want a border on the top of my rectangle.

`box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Zw4QA/317/

Comment: If you want an equal shadow on all four sides you have to set the x and y position to zero and play with the blur value.

Comment: @j08691 I only need it for three sides (left, right, bottom). I don't want anything to appear on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your box shadow to:

```
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 1px 1px 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) -1px 1px 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 1px 1px;
```

You can use multiple box shadows and negative values to pull them to the left or top when needed.

Comment: Thanks. I also found the answer here too http://stackoverflow.com/a/7494032/1179449

Comment: You don't really need the 3rd shadow, I think