# remove box shadow from only top of div?

Tags: css

I am trying to add a box shadow to my div but i only want the shadow to appear on the left, right and bottom of the div, does anyone know or can show me how i might remove only the top shadow from my div?

```css
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

Comment: share complete css and html or create fiddler.

Comment: Simplest, cleanest and best overall solution at this Stack post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493994/set-css3-box-shadow-not-to-be-on-top-of-div

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 Question: how to have no box shadow on the top of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665341/css3-question-how-to-have-no-box-shadow-on-the-top-of-a-div)

Answer (score 13):

As of November 2022 there's a nice, clean way to do this using the CSS `clip-path` property.

```
div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  clip-path: inset(0px -10px -10px -10px);
}
```

Inset will clip away the element from the top, right, bottom, and left edges. For a this shadow in the example we're clipping anything beyond the top bounds, hiding the shadow on the top, and allowing 10px of space for the shadow on all other sides.

It's the clean, ideal solution to the problem in my opinion. Browser support is good, but if you want support in IE11 still you'll want to explore the `polygon` option instead of inset.

Answer (score 12):

The basic Box-shadow values are:

```
box-shadow: [horizontal-offset] [vertical-offset] [blur](optional) [spread](optional) [color]
```

So for example:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

would just be a shadow with no offset

```
box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

would be a shadow with 5px vertical offset, effectively pushing the shadow down, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/TLQs9/

Comment: the only problem of this is that the bottom shadow gets larger by that method.

Comment: @My1 true, there are other methods you could use to avoid that http://stackoverflow.com/a/16900313/1557617

Comment: yeah. found that one already one the same day, but still thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Rather than add an extra div to your markup, you can use `:before` to cover up the box-shadow with absolute positioning and negative margin.

```css
div { 
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

p { 
  padding: 20px; 
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Some container with shadow</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
div {
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -khtml-box-shadow:0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow:0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

- The first value is horizontal position.
- Second value is Vertical position.
- Third value applies blur in shadow.
- Four value spread.

So try that your vertical an horizontal position match with blur and spread

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div{
box-shadow:12px 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow:12px 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:12px 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

When I use this I have a shadow on all sides except the top. You can change the values and it still works. Just don't add a fourth value and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
  div
    {
      box-shadow: 0px 9px 29px rgb(102, 102, 102);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 29px rgb(102, 102, 102);
      -moz-box-shadow:0px 9px 29px rgb(102, 102, 102);
    }
```

[See in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrsbD/21/)

[See More 1](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)

[See More 2](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me. So as an alternative solution I used a patch. Inside the element/div with the box shadow.
Place a second div, width 100% and its background the same color as the main div, then position it to cover over the box-shadow, like so.

```
background-color: your background color?
width:100%;
position:absolute;
height 15px;
left 0; 
top -10px;
```

You may need to tweek the height to patch over the box shadow. But it does work.
plus this trick could be used for any side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use a negative value for the offset

instead of

```
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

You can use

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

You just have to fiddle with the other values to get that shadow thickness that you want.